# Disable telemetry in serilog app insights

Tags: serilog

We can disable telemetry using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration`;
how can we do it using `Serilog.sinks.ApplicationInsights` ?
Actually I need to use a SpecFlow test cases for an api using Serilog and I am getting

> CS8602 warning: dereference of a possibly null reference.

Comment: You need to provide more context - while mind readers do exist, that's harder over the Internet, and.nobody wants to read answers or comments with people guessing what you've done.

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink -Thanks for your reply. I am not looking for any mind reader but since I am new to Application Insights , I am trying to understand the difference between the two packages. It would be helpful if you can share some documentation for the same

Comment: I have no documentation to share. I have never read the source to the package or looked at the docs for AppInsights. The point is you have not told us anything about what you've tried, what you are doing, what your code looks like, what you know, what you don't know. All we have is "I am doing specflow and appinsights and its not working HELP!". This is not a support forum - this is devs helping other devs. If you are getting a compiler error message, it would be helpful to show the code that is triggering that message, and why you are doing that.

Comment: I appreciate this is frustrating for you, but taking 5 mins out of your day to describe your problem better is going to give someone a better chance to help you - if you don't have time to do that, nobody can do anything other than paste you the documentation for specflow, appinsights and C#. ... Or start dragging the problem out of you by doing what amounts to a chat session...